# Why do some Oscar presenters present 2 awards?

Tags: academy-awards

The 2017 Oscars was the first I've watched in several years, so I'm not sure how long this has been going on. Kate McKinnon and Jason Bateman presented 2 awards: Best Hair & Makeup and Best Costume Design. There were other pairs who also presented 2 awards, but I can't recall who or which awards.

Why and when did the Academy start having multiple awards presented by the same pair of presenters?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that has been happening for quite a while now.

Comment: Cheaper and quicker.

Comment: Adding onto the comment from @Paulie_D, I've noticed that those awards are in a similar category ("sound editing" and "sound mixing"), and are not considered _major_ awards such as Best Actress or Best Picture.